# Draw Lines Web Page

Tags: javascript, web, graphics, drawing

Found this wonderful library to draw lines on webpage 
    http://www.walterzorn.de/en/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm

I actually worked fine for me on page for drawing the line.But, i want to show arrow at one end of the line. I could not find it the library [i think], so can anybody suggest me on the same.

Comment: You can draw triangle image with rotation at the end of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use this library. Just draw three lines with the same first coordinates, but different second coordinates, calculated using rotation and scale transformations.

Comment: Your suggestion was fine, but seems not fitting well in my requirement. Thanks